# Using Google Sign Up with Google Drive API v3

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I would like to add to my Android application ability to store a file on users GoogleDrive. The application uses Xamarin.Android.
As Google documentation says:(https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#AboutAuthorization)

> About authorization protocols Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to
>   authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If
>   your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization
>   are handled for you.

Google Sing-In is possible and should be easier. 
BUT,
all Google SingIn samples that I found end with fetching of user's attributes, like e-mail or Last name, but I cant, find how to use received user's attributes for Google Drive or any other API authorization.
For example, from Google site:

```
    GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

    // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
    updateUI(account);
```

or in following C# example:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == SING_IN_ACTIVITY_RESULT)
    {
        GoogleSignInResult res = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if(res.IsSuccess)
        {
            GoogleSignInAccount googleAccount = res.SignInAccount;
        }
    }
}
```

while Drive API service requires UserCredential object that is a result of OAuth2 procedure:

```
     { //...
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    }

    // Create Drive API service.
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
```

How can be converted GoogleSignInAccount to UserCredential?

Answer (score 0):

GoogleSingIn just works to sign in, you can't convert the result into an UserCredential and then use google drive....

The solutons would be look for an specific google drive API

https://developers.google.com/drive